# 2 buttons are not performing any sort of functionality

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 buttons which I want to do the following but it is not doing anything at the moment:

Enable Button:

- Button onclick will access the `enableHandler()` function, if user
  confirms the confirmation, then navigate the user to the
  `penaltymarks.php` page.

Disable Button:

- Button onclick will access the `disableHandler()` function, if user
  confirms the confirmation, then navigate the user to the
  `completes.php` page and the ajax will navigate to the
  `completesession.php` page in the background.

How can I get my buttons to perform the above because nothing is happening with the code I have at the moment. Do I need `<form>` tags by the way as I have not included form tags in my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {   

    enableHandler() {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
       {
         $.ajax({
           url: "penaltymarks.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
      }
    };

});

$(function() {   

    disableHandler() {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to disable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
       {
         $.ajax({
           url: "sessioncomplete.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
      }
    };

});

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="enablePenalty" value="Enable Penalty Marks"/></td>
<td><input type="button" id="disablePenalty" value="Do Not Enable Penalty Marks"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#enablePenalty').click(function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
    {
      window.location = "penaltymarks.php",
      return true;
    }
 });

  $('#disablePenalty').click(function () {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to disable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
    {
       $.ajax({
           url: "sessioncomplete.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
      window.location = "complete.php",
      return true;
    }
 });


</script>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Check in your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your full working code:

```
$(function() {

    function enableHandler() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) {
            window.location = "penaltymarks.php";
            return true;
        }
    }

    function disableHandler() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to disable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) {
            $.when($.ajax({
                url: "sessioncomplete.php",
                async: false,
                type: "POST"
            })).then(window.location = "completes.php");
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Enable Button
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        enableHandler();
    });

    // Disable Button
    $('#button2').click(function() {
        disableHandler();
    });

});​
```

In the function `disableHandler` I have used [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). This is used here to wait for the ajax call to finish and after its complete jump to the `completes.php` page.

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared them as functions at all, first you have to do that

```
$(function() {   

function enableHandler() {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
   {
     $.ajax({
       url: "penaltymarks.php",
       async: false,
       type: "POST"
     });
     return true;
  }
};



});
```

Then you get hold of the button and prepare the event handler.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    enableHandler();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the ajax function to navigate to a new page, use `window.location` instead.

```
window.location = "penaltymarks.php",
```

You also need to hook the code to form, with jQuery you can do the following:

```
 $('#buttonID').click(function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
    {
      window.location = "penaltymarks.php",
      return true;
    }
 });
```

Comment: I still see a problem -- check out Palash's code.  You need to use `then` in java since ajax is non-synchronous

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling two unnamed functions to declare your functions inside them, try using this syntax:

```
$(document).ready( function(){



   function enableHandler() {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to enable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
       {
         $.ajax({
           url: "penaltymarks.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
       }
    };

  function disableHandler() {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to disable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) 
   {
     $.ajax({
       url: "sessioncomplete.php",
       async: false,
       type: "POST"
     });
     return true;
   }
  };

    //Here you can call functions
    $('#EnableButton').click( enableHandler());

});
```